# What is one word for - endlessly spread in all directions?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

What is one word for - endlessly spread in all directions? It may  be in context of a forest.

Comment: A thesaurus entry for 'spread' might help.

Comment: It didn't. I need 'continuation'.

Comment: I think this is a request for help with creative writing, which makes it Off Topic.

Answer (score 4):

**Boundless** meaning without bound.

> adjective: having no bounds; infinite or vast; unlimited:
>   ([dictionaryreference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boundless))

"We flew across a boundless forest, with trees as far as the eye could see."

Comment: Thank you. I used it here - http://plinky.com/links/1XBs

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would be useful. Here are some choices for forests:

> The forest covered the land.
>
> The land was carpeted by forests.
>
> The forest spread out as far as the eye could see.

UPDATE: Based on the example sentence you posted in the comments, I would go for one of these:

> The *endless* forest stood before me.
>
> The *sprawling* forest stood before me.

Comment: I'm afraid but I'm in search for an adjective that would define 'endlessness'/'continuity'.
Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @Racer could you give an example sentence?

Comment: The _____ forest stood before me.

Comment: @Racer see update, _sprawling_ should work.

Comment: Okay. What for 'tidily sprawling'?

Answer (score 1):

As in the case of the universe, it is ***"ever expanding"***, or if it its outer edges are fixed, but out of sight, you can say ***"vast"***, (like the ocean) or more hyperbolic, ***vast beyond comprehension"***.  ***"Limitless"*** might also work.

Comment: +1 for _vast_. [Some dictionaries](http://www.wordnik.com/words/vast) define _vast_ as "a boundless .. space" or "very great in area," which would work well for a forest.

Answer (score 0):

Might depend on the context of what you're writing (e.g., Narnia versus On Nature), but here are a few ideas:

- infinite forest
- endless forest
- omnipresent forest
- omnidirectional forest

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear to me based on the poorly-explained situation given by the question that the word in question is "homogenous".

A "homogenous forest" is one which is self-similar in all directions regardless of dimension, a poor physical analogy that was latched onto by the poster and may have caused his inability to get that answer out of people on this site.

Comment: I wonder how this post answers the question.

Comment: It gives the word 'homogenous' as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to but different from *boundless*, but how about *unbounded*?

M-W:

> [*unbounded*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbounded): not limited in any way

Your example:

> The forest was *unbounded* in all directions.

That is, the forest was without boundary.